# combing two vectors in R in completely different style

Tags: r, vector

I want to combine two vector in R in completely new format . I have two vector

```
a<-1:5

b<-11:15
```

i want to make a new vector which contains both a and b but not in continuous format . i want this new vector in (key,value) kind of format. let call it 'd'.

```
(1,11) (2,12) (3,13) (4,14) (5,15)
```

and whenever i tried to call first element of this i want (1,11) in return and so on for the rest of the elements.

furthermore if one is able to solve this please do tell me the way i can plot my solution where i can plot like 1 as lower extreme and 11 as higher extreme point on a same horizontal line like

```
1..........................11

  2...........................12

    3............................13

      4.............................14

        5..............................15
```

Comment: Not clear. If you just try `plot(a,b)`, you plot the points that you seem to want. If you want just a vector with alternating values, try `c(rbind(a,b))`. If you want a `matrix`, try `cbind(a,b)`. If you want a named vector, `setNames(b,a)` is maybe what you want.

Comment: if you are more looking for a list `setNames(as.list(b), a)`

Comment: @nicola  please see the updated version of the problem . Hope you can get what i want

Answer (score 1):

I think you are looking for a list? I listed some ideas that could solve your problem. Maybe you can specify your questions based on this answer.

```
a<-1:5
b<-11:15

# create a list
list = vector(5, mode = "list")
for(index in 1:length(a)){
  list[[index]] = c(a[index], b[index])
}
list
unlist(list)
plot(unlist(list))
plot(a,b)
```

Comment: List is not exactly what i am looking for. but may be somewhat similar to that .

Answer (score 1):

you can use mapply :

```
pairs <- mapply(c,a,b, SIMPLIFY = F)
```

plot(a,b) works as @nicola mentioned in the comment. If you want to plot values(b) against key(a) then :

```
barplot(height = b,names.arg = a)
```

Comment: it is somewhat close but not exactly the same. Reading list becomes difficult for large data. Please tell me another alternate . I am thinking of my solution to look like a vector with paired values of vector a and vector b

Comment: `pairs[[1]]` gives 1,11 & `pairs[[2]]` gives 2,12 and so on. this is what you need right?

Comment: [1] (1,11) (2,12) (3,13) (4,14) (5,15)

Comment: then you can use `as.tuple(pairs[[1]])` from package sets. loop through all pair elements.

Answer (score 1):

You might want to take a look at `Intervals()`

```
library(intervals)
p <- Intervals(t(mapply(c,a,b)))
plot(p)
```

Which gives:

[image]